# Is there a way to delete that little space between rows in the image gallery?

Tags: html, css, gallery

I've designed a gallery but I can't eliminate the space between rows! Is there a way?

https://civitonia.cargo.site/27997464

Comment: Is your data in an html table? If so, try applying the css `table { border-collapse: collapse; }`

Comment: If that's not the case, then perhaps you have some css that is affecting your page that needs to be fixed.

Comment: Could you please share your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The space is caused by the `line-height` being set to `1`.

Add this to your CSS:

```
bodycopy {
    line-height: 0;
}
```